# Is it possible to create a windows installer for combine an application built with Electron Framework and AutoHotkey Tool?

Tags: build, electron, autohotkey

I have try many way to built the **electron app** with **AutoHotKey** tool as one exe file but still it's didn't work, if you find any way please help me. Here is the **build.js** code:

```
    // C:\Users\sdkca\Desktop\electron-workspace\build.js
    var electronInstaller = require('electron-winstaller');

    // In this case, we can use relative paths
    var settings = {
        // Specify the folder where the built app is located
        appDirectory: './KIT Online Examination System-win32-x64',
        // Specify the existing folder where 
        outputDirectory: './KIT-online-exam-installers',
        // The name of the Author of the app (the name of your company)
        authors: 'Kirirom Institute of Technology.',
        // The name of the executable of your built
        exe: './KIT Online Examination System.exe',
        exe: './AutoHotKey.exe'
    };

    resultPromise = electronInstaller.createWindowsInstaller(settings);

    resultPromise.then(() => {
        console.log

("The installers of your application were succesfully created !");
}, (e) => {
    console.log(`Well, sometimes you are not so lucky: ${e.message}`)
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with electron apps. But since i'm not very sure of what files you are trying to pass, is that "autohotkey.exe" the ahk executable? If it is, have you tried compiling your script and passing the compiled script instead?

Comment: @scso yes I have compiling the script to execute the autohotkey.exe already in the main.js